# I want my app to recognize when two buttons are held at the same time

Tags: android, button, kotlin, ontouchlistener

I want to have an activity display to the screen only in circumstances where two specific buttons are held at the exact same time. I'm using onTouchListeners to check when they're held and trying to use a when statement to see when both are true, but I'm not seeing the output for the when statement.

```
var button1 = false
var button2 = false

buttonOne.setOnTouchListener { view, motionEvent ->
println("Button 1 is held!")
button1 = true
true
}
buttonTwo.setOnTouchListener { view, motionEvent ->
println("Button 2 is held!")
button2= true
true
}
when (button1 && button2) {
true -> println("Both buttons are held!")
}
```

I expect this result:

```
I/System.out: Button 1 is held!
I/System.out: Button 2 is held!
I/System.out: Both buttons are held!
```

But only get:

```
I/System.out: Button 1 is held!
I/System.out: Button 2 is held!
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not how touches work in Android.  When you first touch a view, that view owns all touch events until one of 2 things happen-  you lift all of your fingers or your parent steals the events.  It will not send some touch events to one view and some to another.  If you want to do this, your touch handler will need to be able to tell when the second finger down is in the other view.

You're going to have to write a much more complicated touch handler that looks for multitouch events and does hit testing to decide when both views are touched.

Comment: I see. Thank you for your help. I'll look further into a multi-touch handler.

Answer (score 0):

You are right to use a TouchListener on both buttons.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener

Then you can watch for particular events MotionEvents.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html

You'll be most interested in the ACTION_DOWN MotionEvent.

If you set flags based on this event and test for the existence of the opposing button_down flag you should be able to tell when both are pressed.

```
var button1 = false
var button2 = false

buttonOne.setOnTouchListener { view, motionEvent ->
  when (motionEvent) {
    ACTION_DOWN -> button1 = true; checkButtons()
    ACTION_CANCEL -> button1 = false
  }
  true
}

buttonTwo.setOnTouchListener { view, motionEvent ->
  when (motionEvent) {
    ACTION_DOWN -> button2 = true; checkButtons()
    ACTION_CANCEL -> button2 = false
  }
  true
}

fun checkButtons {
  if (button1 && button2) {
    println("Both buttons are held!")
  }
}
```